# Best way to include/remove JavaScript file on page resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, include

What is the best way to include JavaScript files and removing them for certain screen sizes.

**Essentially the below:**

```
jQuery(window).on("resize", function () 
{
    if ( jQuery(window).width() > 960) {
        // include 960.js
        // remove low_res.js
    }
    else
    {
        // include low_res.js
        // remove 960s.js
    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the script? Just space out your code in the appropriate part of the if statement.

Comment: Well for one, load speed.

Comment: "Removing" wouldn't really do much of anything - technically, the .js is "removed" as soon as it's executed. You're probably trying to undo or stop its effect - there is no universal way to do this, so it's a good idea to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I have a large matrix of boxes, that is interactive. On hover of a box, another area displays certain text that corresponds to that box. 

When I go down to mobile, I have converted this to a dropdown. But when I resize back up to "desktop" mode the matrix is broken.

Comment: Please update the original post with the parts of the code that are problematic (or, even better, a jsfiddle) so that we can figure out what makes it "broken".

Comment: Hi fstanis. Page here: http://tinyurl.com/nzg3bc3

Comment: @KeithDonegan: No, content for your question goes **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Best way to include/remove JavaScript file on page resize?

Not to. For one thing, removing a `script` element doesn't do anything to the effects of the code that it ran — event handlers hooked up by it aren't removed, globals created by it don't disappear, etc.

Instead, have a single script, and have the code check the width of the page as appropriate.

But if you **really** want to have the scripts be separate, and to demand-load the other one when/if things change, then here's what you'll need to do:

Have each script define a single global (say, `Page960` and `PageLowRes`) which has `init` and `uninit` functions on it, and an `isInitialized` flag it sets to `true` in `init` and `false` in `uninit`. When either of them script loads, it should call its own `init` function. Your switcher code would then look like this:

```
jQuery(window).on("resize", function () 
{
    var use960, newVersion, oldVersion;

    use960 = jQuery(window).width() > 960;
    newVersion = use960 ? "Page960" : "PageLowRes";
    oldVersion = use960 ? "PageLowRes" : "Page960";

    // Already using the "new" version?
    if (window[newVersion] && window[newVersion].isInitialized) {
        // Yes, nothing to do
    } else {
        // No, un-init the old if initialized
        if (window[oldVersion]) {
            window[oldVersion].uninit();
        }

        // Do we already have the new version?
        if (window[newVersion]) {
            // Yes, re-init it
            window[newVersion].init();
        } else {
            // No, load it (it'll init itself)
            $.getScript(use960 ? "960.js" : "low_res.js");
        }
    }
}).resize();
```

I'd suggest adding a delay in there, though, so you're not doing this on every tiny bit of resize...